# how to solve this error to link index and partial view in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an error  on my project in the index view and partial view on asp.net mvc here's my code:

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Customers _model = new Customers();

        var custcategoryList = db.CustomerLists.ToList();

        _model.Customer_List = (from d in custcategoryList
                                select new SelectListItem
                      {
                          Value = d.CustID.ToString(),
                          Text = d.CustCategory
                      }).ToList();

        var qq = (from r in db.CustStatus
                  join a in db.CustomerLists on r.CustID equals a.CustID
                  join b in db.SalesPersons on a.SalesRepID equals b.SalesRepID
                  join c in db.WebStatus on r.WebStatID equals c.WebStatID
                  join d in db.OrderStatus on r.OrderStatID equals d.OrderStatID
                  join e in db.SalesPersons on r.AssignedTo equals e.SalesRepID

                  select new
                  {

                      custID = a.CustID,
                      customername = a.Customer,
                      CUstcategory = a.CustCategory,
                      custstatID = r.CustStatID,
                      region = a.Region,
                  }).ToList();

        _model.Customer_grid = qq;
        return View("CustomerView", _model);

    }


    public ActionResult Filter(string CustCategory)
    {


        int? CustID = Convert.ToInt32(CustCategory);

        var qq = (from a in db.CustomerLists
                  join d in db.CustStatus on a.CustID equals d.CustID
                  //where e.Department_id == department_id
                  select new Customers
                  {
                      CustID=a.CustID,
                      Customer=a.Customer,
                      CustCategory=a.CustCategory,
                      CustStatID=d.CustStatID                      
                  }).ToList();

        return PartialView("CustomerView", qq);


    }



}
```

**Index View**

```
@model Calling_List.Models.Customers
 <tr>
    <td>
        @*@Html.DropDownList("CustID",null, "select",Model.Customer_List)*@
        @Html.DropDownList("lstdepartment", Model.Customer_List, new {@class="form-control"})
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div id="CustomerViewGrid">
            @Html.Partial("CustomerView", Model.Customer_grid)
            @*@Html.ViewBag("Partial1",new Calling_List.Models.Customers());*@
            }
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>

  <script type="text/javascript">
$('#lstdepartment').change(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = '@Url.Action("Filter")';
    $.get(url, { depart: $(this).val() }, function (result) {
        debugger;
        $('#CustomerViewGrid').html(result);
    });
});
```

**Partial View**

```
  @model List<Calling_List.Models.Customers>

<div id="gridposition" style="overflow: scroll; height: 300px; overflow-x: hidden;">
@{
    var grid1 = new WebGrid(source: Model, canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 5, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "gridContent");

    @grid1.GetHtml(mode: WebGridPagerModes.All, tableStyle: "webGrid",
        headerStyle: "header",
        alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
        selectedRowStyle: "select",
        rowStyle: "description",
        htmlAttributes: new { id = "positionGrid" },
        fillEmptyRows: false,

        columns: grid1.Columns(
         grid1.Column("CustID", header: "CustomerID"),
         grid1.Column("Customer", header: "Customername"),
         grid1.Column("Region", header: "Region"),
         grid1.Column("CustCategory", header: "CustomerCategory"),
         grid1.Column("CustStatID", header: "CustStatID")))
}
```

**View Model**

```
public class Customers
{
    public List<SelectListItem> Customer_List { get; set; }
    public List<CustomerList> Customer_grid { get; set; }
    public int CustID { get; set; }
    public string Customer { get; set; }
    public string CustCategory { get; set; }
    public string Branch { get; set; }
    public string Region { get; set; }
    public string ContactName { get; set; }
    public int CustStatID { get; set; }

}
```

i want to filter the Customer's Details based on the selected dropdownlist binded with "custcategory " names and display the details on the webgrid on the partial view.It does display the filtering parameter "custCategory" on the dropdown but it does not display the customers details.

Comment: What error do you get and what line of code produces the error?

Comment: when selecting the "cuscategory" from the dropdown it doesnt do anythng . what it suppose to do is to display all the details to the partial view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your JavaScript like below.

I change the parameter as CustCategory instead of depart that you used.

**Look care Full on the 4th line on my code and your code**

```
$('#lstdepartment').change(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
var url = '@Url.Action("Filter")';
$.get(url, { CustCategory: $(this).val() }, function (result) {
    debugger;
    $('#CustomerViewGrid').html(result);
});
});
```

by change that parameter name it will aromatically takes you to the particular page.

Comment: Have your value properly pass to controller from dropDown ?

Comment: can youu please ask your question in a simple way